# Print a map on html using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable 'page' with following structure:

```
"page": 
{
  "pageId": 1,
  "properties": {
    "name": "abc.png",
    "values": {
      "LastEditor": "user",
      "Text": "Some content"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I have to print 'values' map in a table on my html page like:

```
Name        | Value
----------- | ------------   
LastEditor  | user 
Text        | Some content
```

Content in 'values' is dynamic. Therefore, I cannot hard code LastEditor and Text and print their values.

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys` on the object to get an array of the properties. From there, you just need to run a `foreach` on it, and write the values on DOM.

See the snippet below:

```js
var obj = {
  "values": {
    "LastEditor": "user",
    "Text": "Some content",
    "Some other Property": "Some value"
  }
};

var model = function(obj){
  var self = this;
  
  self.value = ko.observable(obj.values);
}

ko.applyBindings(new model(obj));
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: Object.keys($root.value()) -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: $root.value()[$data]"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to get those key/value pairs.

```js
var json = {
  "page": {
    "pageId": 1,
    "properties": {
      "name": "abc.png",
      "values": {
        "LastEditor": "user",
        "Text": "Some content"
      }
    }
  }
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.data = ko.observableArray();

  for (var key in json.page.properties.values) {
    self.data.push({
      key: key,
      value: json.page.properties.values[key]
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: key"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```